# Admob no funciona en release apk

Tags: android, apk, admob

¿Por qué los ads de Admob no se muestran en la build release de mi apk, pero si en la debug?

En el Log me muestra esto:

```
I/Ads: No fill from ad server.
```

Comment: es importante agregues tu código para saber que estas realizando, revisa [ask].

Comment: Me ha pasado tanto eso como el error 3. Se arreglaron, automáticamente, o más bien, comenzó a funcionar, cuando subí la app a la Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

segun este [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26610383/admob-no-fill-from-ad-server-failed-to-load-ad-3) en ingles

La solucion seria la siguiente.

```
/** Objecto adRequest en testing o debug */
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID").build();

/** Objecto adRequest para produccion*/
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
```

Tu puedes encontrar tu `DEVICE_ID` en el logcat de la siguiente manera:

> I/Ads: Use
>   AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("TEST_DEVICE_ID") to
>   get test ads on this device.

Comment: TEST_DEVICE_ID es para prueba, y comenta el OP que no se muestra en su .apk de release.

Comment: Claro, decia que se usa el primero en prueba y el segundo para cuando ya realices tu apk de realease. @Elenasys